# Using spread operator to add new value to key value pair in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Struggling to figure out how to add a new item to an object from my reducer. This is the payload I am receiving `GH`

This is the relevant code in my reducer

```
const initialForm = { 
    nationality: '',
}
function addName(state= initialForm, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_NEW_NATIONALITY:
            console.log('nationality',action.payload.name)
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.payload.nationality]: action.payload.value
            }
        default:
            return state
    }   
}
```

and my action creators

```
export const addFullName = newName => dispatch => {
    console.log(newName)
    axios.get(`https://api.nationalize.io?name=${newName.name}`)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({ type: ADD_NEW_NATIONALITY, payload: res.data.country[0].country_id})
        })
```

Please help me figure this out

Comment: What's the problem/error then? Your code seems good

Comment: Nothing is getting pushed to state, I get undefined when I console log `action.payload.nationality` @BaoHuynhLam

Comment: Why don't you assign the new object to a variable, log out that variable and then return it. That might give you an indication. I can't tell what's wrong with it from here.

Answer (score 2):

Your `payload` is just a plain value (not an object), so you cannot find `action.payload.name` and `action.payload.value`

And similarly, you cannot find `action.payload.nationality` either.

Here is how your action looks like

```
{ type: ADD_NEW_NATIONALITY, payload: 1} //`1` is country_id
```

To set `nationality` correctly, you can check the below implementation

```
const initialForm = { 
    nationality: '',
}
function addName(state= initialForm, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_NEW_NATIONALITY:
            return {
                ...state,
                nationality: action.payload //update your `nationality` property with a plain value from `payload`
            }
        default:
            return state
    }   
}
```